# ArcGIS Online Not Accepting CSS for Transparency

Tags: css, arcgis

I am *attempting* to make the background of an element (timecontainer) transparent by using ArcGIS Online's custom CSS option.

Using inspector in Firefox, I was able to find the element that needed to be adjusted ([posted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woQUU.png)). 
The background-color should be changed to rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.41), as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rInKR.png).

Using a CSS editor, I drafted the following:

```css
.esriTimeSlider .ts {
  padding: 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  padding-top: 155px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 1px;
}

#timeContainer {
  width: 750px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://imagebackground");
}

.timeInfo .bg .fg .window-bottom-left {
  background-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.41);
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: This looks like it would be more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/236480/115